# GetValue Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase structure as follows:

```
Orders
  HALa1r5un1gkcddZzzDRQWxPCwm2 //This is the UserUID
    1515589315695                //This is This is the order code
      total : 4000                  //This is the total order amount

    1515592859285
      total : 2000
```

How can I get the total amount of the above two orders. The result will be: 6000

I have another question. After I received 6000 results, how do I convert 6000 to 60? I want to move from a number that has thousands into a number of tens.
Example: 1000 -> 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that  `Orders` node is a direct child of your Firebase root and `total` is declared of type `int`, to solve this, please use the following code:

```
String uid = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Orders").child(uid);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            int total = ds.child("total").getValue(Integer.class);
            sum = sum + total;
        }
        Log.d("TAG", sum);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

The output will be: 6000

To convert `6000` to `60`, simply divide `sum` to `100`, or take a look at [Java NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Comment: Tks very much :))

Comment: 2nd question do you know the answer? Help me, please?